How do two things attracted to each other move in mechanics?
Okay very simply:
If you have two objects in 1D and they're both attracted to each other by some force (say there's a spring pulling them both towards each other, or Coulomb's Law or something)...
How do you describe their motion? Do you fix one of them as "still" and make a reference frame around it where the other is accelerating at it via a = F/m or do BOTH of them accelerate at each other, at the same acceleration derived from a = F/m OR do both of them accelerate at each other but at half the acceleration of the full thing?
Force is really simple when it's just pushing something or colliding; something enacts force on some other thing, and that other thing accelerates. But when they're both attracted to each other, how do you conserve for energy there?


How do you describe their motion?

However makes the problem easiest.  One of the neat things about physics is that you can frame the problem differently, work the math, and come up with the same physical answer.  You can set the problem up in the reference frame of one object (such that it does not move in that frame), run the equations of motion for that frame, and compute the motion of the other.  Or you can set the problem up in an inertial reference frame (such that both move), run the equations of motion for that inertial frame, and compute the motion of both.  When you do, you will get consistent results.  The results in one frame will describe the same motion as the results in the other frame.  The numbers will be different, but the meaning behind them will be the same.
We usually pick a reference frame that makes the computations easiest.  We'll pick it to cancel out some obnoxious force, or to minimize the effects of non-inertial frames.  But there's no "right" way to compute the motion.  You'll get the same motion regardless of the frame you use.  You'll use different numbers to describe that motion, but it will be the same motion.

But when they're both attracted to each other, how do you conserve for energy there?

You conserve energy just like always.  There's no particular trick here.  What might be causing confusion is that we sometimes treat objects as having potential energy.  It's more accurate to say that the configuration of the whole system has potential energy.  If the position of one object is $x_1$ and the position of the other object is $x_2$, we might say that the energy of the system is a function $E(x_1, x_2)$.  If there are no interactions between the objects, that function can often be broken up into $E_1(x_1) + E_2(x_2)$, which points towards being able to say each object has some "energy."  However, in the case where there's interactions (like the attractive forces you describe), it doesn't always nicely break up like that.  So we just end up conserving $E(x_1, x_2)$

In case of no external forces, just mutual interactions, like gravitation, Coulomb force or spring force that is net same on both, we take the reference frame as center of mass which allows us to conserve the linear momentum about the center of mass. Then we also conserve the mechanical energy of the system. If an external force except the mutual attraction also acts, then we consider the center of mass again but in that case it will also accelerate. But, the linear momentum about it will usually always be conserved since net force even in accelerating frame of reference on complete system sums up and adjusts such that it becomes zero. But since center of mass frame of reference will be non inertial frame of reference, we apply work energy theorem.

In case of external force, the force sums up to zero after taking the pseudo forces into the account since you are on a non inertial frame of reference.
